# Pycharmで一行ずつ実行

Tags: python

普段はRstudioやSpyderを使っていますが、Pycharmを使おうと試みている状況です。

前の２つのIDEのように、選択部分のみを実行する方法はPycharmにはあるのでしょうか。
ブレークポイントを設定してデバッグをする方法は調べたら見つけましたがやはりちょっと違うような気がして質問させていただきました。

どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

選択部分のみを実行するのは、ショートカットで `Alt+Shift+E`です。また、右クリックでメニューから `Execute Selection in Console` を選択することで可能です。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]